# ASP.NET MVC Redirect Partial View Request If it is not from a View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, partial-views

I have some partial views and corresponding action methods in a controller. I call them using `Html.Action("PartialView")` helper in some Views. This works fine.

However when i type the url of the action of the partial view into the address bar of my browser, controller sends me the partial view back ***alone***(without any wrapping view or layout). This seems weird. I want my controller to redirect request of actions returning partial view to index action but not `Html.Action()` helpers

How can i do that?

Comment: There isn't really a reliable way to know for certain what UI originated an HTTP request.  Why do you want to do this anyway?  What problem is being solved by this?

Comment: I just dont want the user see weird views without layout or wrapping view

Comment: You can't prevent the user from manually modifying their UX.  Basically, this is a made-up problem that doesn't really need to be solved.  The application presents the UX as intended.  If the user chooses to deviate from that and manually make requests for data, that's ok.  As long as the authorization is maintained, nothing bad is happening.

Comment: @David Becouse of your comment I thought it was not possible. However i found what i need after some search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search in the internet i found the answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423214/how-can-i-tell-if-my-action-is-being-called-by-renderaction)

So what i need was just to redirect the request by checking the  `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` in the specific action.